# Returning a value inside a double struct C++

Tags: c++, struct, nodes

I want to return the degree from my Term struct.From my understanding I need to access the Node->Term->Degree however my function doesn't take a Node as a argument so how would I approach this?

```
//This function returns the degree for example
//a.degree returns degree
int Polynomial::degree() const{

}

struct Term{
   int coeff;
   int degree;
};
struct Node {
   Term *term;
   Node *next;
};
```

These are my structs.

Polynomial.cpp is as followed (shortened) :

```
using namespace std;
struct Term{
   int coeff;
   int degree;
};

struct Node {
   Term *term;
   Node *next;
};

int Polynomial::degree() const{

}
```

Polynomial.h is as followed (shortened) :

```
using namespace std;
Class Polynomial {
struct Term{
   int coeff;
   int degree;
};

struct Node {
   Term *term;
   Node *next;
};

public:
int degree() const;

private:
Node * poly;
```

Comment: can you provide the code of your class Polynomial?

Comment: You must be having a Node object as a member of the class. You can access it through the member variable. If not you will need to pass it in as a parameter to the function.

Comment: If the node object is a member of the class, how would i access it ?

Comment: Depends on how it's defined. Post code of `Polynomial`.

Comment: Please give some more details on your implementation.

Comment: @user3249265: Was you problem solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you do the following:

```
int Polynomial::degree() const{
    // Here add your code to check if the pointers are null and
    // implement your early return or exception handling strategy.
    // Below is how to get the degree value using Node type data member
    return poly->term->degree;
}
```

This is ONLY how to get the degree using poly. Please do not forget the nullity check before trying to access the value.

Comment: I just notice my private had a Node * poly, and i used that to access the functions. Thanks!

Comment: I don't see any checks here. See my answer, it's much safer. If you do it this way, you will get wrong behaviour if `poly` or `poly->term` is `nullptr`.

Comment: @MateuszGrzejek: He is asking how to reach the degree. Of course this is not a complete code just reminds him how to get what he needs. Null check etc is up to his coding and is not the question here. The original question was answered and it was accepted. Deal with that :)